# How to delete an ascii moving JS element from page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ascii

I don't understand how I can remove the floating ASCII inscription from the screen. The site is incredibly balanced in terms of elements and very neat. If you touch anything, everything breaks immediately. I will be very grateful! I'm just starting to figure out JS and site layout, it's quite difficult to switch to them after game development. By the way, the site is not mine, I found it on the Internet and decided to explore it for educational purposes. I've been puzzling over how it works for two days now.

INDEX

```
        <pre aria-hidden="true"></pre>
        <script src="boot%EF%B9%9620221107125354.js"></script>
        <script>

            // Parse location
            const url = new URL(location)
            const src = url.searchParams
            // if mode is set to 'screensaver' the navigation will be hidden
            const mode  = (src.get('mode') || '').toLowerCase()
            // color can be set to 'true' for color cycle,
            // or 'white' for full contrast;
            // othewrise gray is used
            const color = (src.get('color') || '').toLowerCase()
            // word can be any alphanumeirc string, but must be of length 3
            // othwerwise a randomised internal dict will be used
            const word  = (url.hash.substr(1) || src.get('word') || '').toLowerCase()

            // Boot
            ertdfgcvb.boot({word, mode, color})

            // Old “tiroir” code
            const s = shuffle([
                // ---- cheers
                'Hi',
                'Yo',
                'Ciao',
                'Viva',
                'Salut',
                'Hello',
                'Grüezi',
                'Cheers',
                'Prosit',
                'Oooooh',
                'Olà olà',
                'Bonjour',
                'Namaste',
                'Guten Tag',
                'Shaba-daba',
                'Go to hell',
                'Buona notte',
                'Buenas dias',
                'Hasta la victoria',
                // ---- love
                'I love you',
                'I hate you',
                // '“I ♥ ♠ ♦ ♣”',
                'I love my cat',
                'I love my dog',
                'I want to be your slave',
                // ---- thats
                'Life is life',
                'I liked my dinner',
                'Gilgamesh is my father',
                'I don’t want to write you',
                'It’s time for a new haircut',
                'Sex or fox are better than fax',
                'It’s common to say it’s common',
                'Aaaah is not the same as ooooh',
                // ---- colors
                'Blue is my favourite color',
                'Pink is my favourite color',
                'Gray is my favourite color',
                'Ocra is my favourite color',
                // ---- numbers
                'Two has three letters',
                'Three has five letters',
                'Five has four letters',
                'Four has four letters',
                'π is close to, but not exactly 3.1415',
                // 'that 1 one stays to 2 twos like 3 trees stay to 4 Fords',
                // ---- animals
                'Slick worms eat silk',
                'Sheep sings while ship sinks',
                'Gold is fish and golf is dish',
                'I saw a cat sleeping in a box',
                'The fly flies and the flies fly',
                // 'that a bird’s burden is the weight of a feather',
                // 'that bird is feather’s father but not vice-versa',
            ])

            let c = 0;
            const e = document.querySelector('.tiroir')
            function swap(){
                c = ++c % s.length
                e.href = 'mailto:andreas@ertdfgcvb.xyz?subject=' + s[c]
                e.innerText = s[c]
            }
            swap()
            setInterval(swap, 9000)

            function shuffle(array){
                for(let i=array.length-1; i>0; i--){
                    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i)
                    ;[array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]]
                }
                return array
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS

```
var ertdfgcvb = function(t) {
    "use strict";
    var e = {
        preferredElementNodeName: "PRE",
        render: function(t, e) {
            const i = t.settings.element;
            i.style.backgroundColor = t.settings.background,
                i.style.color = t.settings.color, i.style.fontWeight = t.settings.weight, (t.rows != r || t.cols != o) && (o = t.cols, r = t.rows, n.length = 0);
            for (; i.childElementCount < r;) {
                const t = document.createElement("span");
                t.style.display = "block", i.appendChild(t)
            }
            for (; i.childElementCount > r;) i.removeChild(i.lastChild);
            for (let l = 0; l < r; l++) {
                const r = l * o;
                let c = !1;
                for (let t = 0; t < o; t++) {
                    const o = t + r,
                        s = e[o],
                        i = n[o];
                    a(s, i) || (c = !0, n[o] = { ...s
                    })
                }
                if (0 == c) continue;
                let h = "",
                    d = {},
                    u = !1;
                for (let n = 0; n < o; n++) {
                    const o = e[n + r];
                    if (o.beginHTML && (u && (h += "</span>", d = {}, u = !1), h += o.beginHTML), !s(o, d)) {
                        u && (h += "</span>");
                        const e = o.color === t.settings.color ? null : o.color,
                            n = o.background === t.settings.background ? null : o.background,
                            r = o.weight === t.settings.weight ? null : o.weight;
                        let a = "";
                        e && (a += "color:" + e + ";"),
                            n && (a += "background:" + n + ";"), r && (a += "font-weight:" + r + ";"), a && (a = ' style="' + a + '"'), h += "<span" + a + ">", u = !0
                    }
                    h += o.char, d = o, o.endHTML && (u && (h += "</span>", d = {}, u = !1), h += o.endHTML)
                }
                u && (h += "</span>"),
                    i.childNodes[l].innerHTML = h
            }
        }
    };
    const n = [];
    let o, r;

    function a(t, e) {
        return "object" == typeof t && ("object" == typeof e && (t.char === e.char && (t.weight === e.weight && (t.color === e.color && t.background === e.background))))
    }

    function s(t, e) {
        return t.weight === e.weight && (t.color === e.color && t.background === e.background)
    }
    var i = {
        preferredElementNodeName: "CANVAS",
        render: function(t, e) {
            const n = t.settings.element,
                o = devicePixelRatio,
                r = t.cols,
                a = t.rows,
                s = t.metrics,
                i = s.cellWidth,
                l = Math.round(s.lineHeight),
                c = t.settings;
            c.canvasSize ? (n.width = c.canvasSize.width * o, n.height = c.canvasSize.height * o, n.style.width = c.canvasSize.width + "px", n.style.height = c.canvasSize.height + "px") : (n.width = t.width * o, n.height = t.height * o);
            const h = " " + s.fontSize + "px " + s.fontFamily,
                d = c && c.background ? c.background : "white",
                u = c && c.color ? c.color : "black",
                f = c && c.weight ? c.color : "400";
            n.style.backgroundColor = c.background || "white";
            const g = n.getContext("2d");
            if (g.fillStyle = d, g.fillRect(0, 0, n.width, n.height), g.save(), g.scale(o, o), c.canvasOffset) {
                const t = c.canvasOffset,
                    e = Math.round("auto" == t.x ? (n.width / o - r * i) / 2 : t.x),
                    s = Math.round("auto" == t.y ? (n.height / o - a * l) / 2 : t.y);
                g.translate(e, s)
            }
            g.fillStyle = u, g.textBaseline = "top";
            for (let t = 0; t < a; t++)
                for (let n = 0; n < r; n++) {
                    const o = e[t * r + n],
                        a = n * i,
                        s = t * l;
                    o.background && o.background != d && (g.fillStyle = o.background || d, g.fillRect(Math.round(a), s, Math.ceil(i), l)), g.font = (o.weight || f) + h,
                        g.fillStyle = o.color || u, g.fillText(o.char, a, s)
                }
            g.restore()
        }
    };
    class l {
        constructor() {
            this.frames = 0, this.ptime = 0, this.fps = 0
        }
        update(t) {
            return this.frames++,
                t >= this.ptime + 1e3 && (this.fps = 1e3 * this.frames / (t - this.ptime), this.ptime = t, this.frames = 0), this.fps
        }
    }
    var c = function(t, e) {
            try {
                return localStorage.setItem(t, JSON.stringify(e)), !0
            } catch (t) {
                return !1
            }
        },
        h = function(t, e = {}) {
            const n = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(t));
            return Object.assign(e, n), e
        };
    const d = {
            canvas: i,
            text: e
        },
        u = {
            element: null,
            cols: 0,
            rows: 0,
            once: !1,
            fps: 30,
            renderer: "text",
            background: "",
            color: "",
            weight: "",
            allowSelect: !1,
            restoreState: !1
        };

    function f(t, e, n = {}) {
        return new Promise((function(o) {
            const r = { ...u,
                    ...e,
                    ...t.settings
                },
                a = {
                    time: 0,
                    frame: 0,
                    cycle: 0
                },
                s = "currentState";
            let i;
            r.restoreState && (h(s, a), a.cycle++), r.element ? "canvas" == r.renderer ? "CANVAS" == r.element.nodeName ? i = d[r.renderer] : console.warn("This renderer expects a canvas target element.") : "CANVAS" != r.element.nodeName ? i = d[r.renderer] : console.warn("This renderer expects a text target element.") : (i = d[r.renderer] || d.text, r.element = document.createElement(i.preferredElementNodeName), document.body.appendChild(r.element));
            const f = [],
                m = {
                    x: 0,
                    y: 0,
                    pressed: !1,
                    px: 0,
                    py: 0,
                    ppressed: !1
                };
            var w;
            r.element.addEventListener("pointermove", (t => {
                    const e = r.element.getBoundingClientRect();
                    m.x = t.clientX - e.left, m.y = t.clientY - e.top, f.push("pointerMove")
                })),
                r.element.addEventListener("pointerdown", (t => {
                    m.pressed = !0, f.push("pointerDown")
                })), r.element.addEventListener("pointerup", (t => {
                    m.pressed = !1, f.push("pointerUp")
                })), r.element.style.fontStrech = "normal",
                r.allowSelect || ((w = r.element).style.userSelect = "none", w.style.webkitUserSelect = "none", w.style.mozUserSelect = "none", w.dataset.selectionEnabled = "false"), document.fonts.ready.then((e => {
                    let o = 3;
                    ! function e() {
                        --o > 0 ? requestAnimationFrame(e) : function() {
                            M = p(r.element);
                            const e = g(a, r, M, b);
                            "function" == typeof t.boot && t.boot(e, x, n);
                            requestAnimationFrame(N)
                        }()
                    }()
                }));
            const b = new l,
                y = Object.freeze({
                    color: r.color,
                    background: r.background,
                    weight: r.weight
                }),
                x = [];
            let M;
            let v = 0;
            const S = 1e3 / r.fps,
                k = a.time;
            let A, E;

            function N(e) {
                const l = e - v;
                if (l < S) return void(r.once || requestAnimationFrame(N));
                const h = g(a, r, M, b);
                b.update(e), v = e - l % S, a.time = e + k, a.frame++, c(s, a);
                const d = {
                    x: m.x / M.cellWidth,
                    y: m.y / M.lineHeight,
                    pressed: m.pressed,
                    p: {
                        x: m.px / M.cellWidth,
                        y: m.py / M.lineHeight,
                        pressed: m.ppressed
                    }
                };
                if (m.px = m.x, m.py = m.y, m.ppressed = m.pressed, A != h.cols || E != h.rows) {
                    A = h.cols, E = h.rows, x.length = h.cols * h.rows;
                    for (let t = 0; t < x.length; t++) x[t] = { ...y,
                        char: " "
                    }
                }
                if ("function" == typeof t.pre && t.pre(h, d, x, n), "function" == typeof t.main)
                    for (let e = 0; e < h.rows; e++) {
                        const o = e * h.cols;
                        for (let r = 0; r < h.cols; r++) {
                            const a = r + o,
                                s = t.main({
                                    x: r,
                                    y: e,
                                    index: a
                                }, h, d, x, n);
                            x[a] = "object" == typeof s && null !== s ? { ...x[a],
                                ...s
                            } : { ...x[a],
                                char: s
                            }, Boolean(x[a].char) || 0 === x[a].char || (x[a].char = " ")
                        }
                    }
                for ("function" == typeof t.post && t.post(h, d, x, n), i.render(h, x, r); f.length > 0;) {
                    const e = f.shift();
                    e && "function" == typeof t[e] && t[e](h, d, x)
                }
                r.once || requestAnimationFrame(N), o(h)
            }
        }))
    }

    function g(t, e, n, o) {
        const r = e.element.getBoundingClientRect(),
            a = e.cols || Math.floor(r.width / n.cellWidth),
            s = e.rows || Math.floor(r.height / n.lineHeight);
        return Object.freeze({
            frame: t.frame,
            time: t.time,
            cols: a,
            rows: s,
            metrics: n,
            width: r.width,
            height: r.height,
            settings: e,
            runtime: Object.freeze({
                cycle: t.cycle,
                fps: o.fps
            })
        })
    }

    function p(t) {
        const e = getComputedStyle(t),
            n = e.getPropertyValue("font-family"),
            o = parseFloat(e.getPropertyValue("line-height")),
            r = parseFloat(e.getPropertyValue("font-size")),
            a = ("CANVAS" == t.nodeName ? t : document.createElement("canvas")).getContext("2d");
        a.font = r + "px " + n;
        const s = a.measureText("".padEnd(10, "x")).width / 10,
            i = {
                aspect: s / o,
                cellWidth: s,
                lineHeight: o,
                fontFamily: n,
                fontSize: r,
                _update: function() {
                    const e = p(t);
                    for (var n in e) "number" != typeof e[n] && "string" != typeof e[n] || (i[n] = e[n])
                }
            };
        return i
    }
    class m {
        constructor(t) {
            this.DOMElement = t
        }
        updateBB() {
            this.bb = this.DOMElement.getBoundingClientRect()
        }
        property(t) {
            return getComputedStyle(this.DOMElement).getPropertyValue(t).trim()
        }
        width(t) {
            return Math.round(this.bb.width / t.cellWidth)
        }
        height(t) {
            return Math.round(this.bb.height / t.lineHeight)
        }
        x(t) {
            return Math.round(this.bb.left / t.cellWidth)
        }
        y(t) {
            return Math.round(this.bb.top / t.lineHeight)
        }
        background() {
            return getComputedStyle(this.DOMElement).backgroundColor
        }
        update(t) {
            return {
                x: x(t),
                y: y(t),
                width: width(t),
                height: height(t)
            }
        }
    }

    function w(t, e, n) {
        return t < e ? e : t > n ? n : t
    }

    function b(t, e, n) {
        return t * (1 - n) + e * n
    }

    function M(t, e, n) {
        const o = w((n - t) / (e - t), 0, 1);
        return o * o * (3 - 2 * o)
    }

    function v(t, e, n, o, r) {
        if (t < 0 || t >= o) return {};
        if (e < 0 || e >= r) return {};
        return n[t + e * o]
    }

    function S(t, e, n, o, r, a) {
        if (e < 0 || e >= r) return;
        if (n < 0 || n >= a) return;
        const s = e + n * r,
            i = "object" == typeof o[s] ? o[s] : {
                char: o[s]
            };
        o[s] = { ...i,
            ...t
        }
    }

    function k(t, e, n, o, r, a, s, i) {
        for (let l = n; l < n + r; l++)
            for (let n = e; n < e + o; n++) S(t, n, l, a, s, i)
    }

    function A(t, e, n, o, r, a) {
        let s, i;
        "object" == typeof t ? (s = t.text, i = { ...t
        }, delete i.text) : s = t;
        let l = e,
            c = n;
        const h = [];
        return s.split("\n").forEach(((t, n) => {
                t.split("").forEach(((t, n) => {
                    l = e + n, S({
                        char: t,
                        ...i
                    }, l, c, o, r, a)
                }));
                const s = v(e, c, o, r, a),
                    d = v(e + t.length - 1, c, o, r, a);
                h.push({
                    first: s,
                    last: d
                }), c++
            })),
            c = Math.max(n, c - 1), {
                offset: {
                    col: l,
                    row: c
                },
                wrapInfo: h
            }
    }

    function E(t, e = 0) {
        if (0 == e) return function(t) {
            let e = 0,
                n = 0,
                o = 0;
            for (let r = 0; r < t.length; r++) {
                "\n" == t[r] ? (o = 0, e++) : (o++, n = Math.max(n, o))
            }
            return {
                text: t,
                numLines: e,
                maxWidth: n
            }
        }(t);
        const n = t.split("\n");
        let o = "",
            r = 0,
            a = 0;
        for (const t of n) {
            const n = t.split(" ");
            let s = 0;
            for (const t of n) 0 == s ? (o += t, s = t.length, r = Math.max(r, s)) : s + 1 + t.length <= e ? (o += " " + t, s += t.length + 1, r = Math.max(r, s)) : (o += "\n" + t, s = t.length + 1, a++);
            o += "\n", a++
        }
        return o = o.slice(0, -1), "\n" == o.charAt(o.length - 1) && a--, {
            text: o,
            numLines: a,
            maxWidth: r
        }
    }
    class N {
        constructor(t, e) {
            this.width = t,
                this.height = e, this.data = new Array(t * e).fill(0)
        }
        setBmp(t, e, n) {
            for (let o = 0; o < t.height; o++)
                for (let r = 0; r < t.width; r++) {
                    const a = e + r + (o + n) * this.width;
                    this.data[a] = t.get(r, o)
                }
        }
        get(t, e) {
            return t < 0 || t >= this.width || e < 0 || e >= this.height ? 0 : this.data[t + e * this.width]
        }
        sample(t, e) {
            const n = t * this.width - .5,
                o = e * this.height - .5;
            let r = Math.floor(n),
                a = Math.floor(o),
                s = r + 1,
                i = a + 1;
            const l = n - r,
                c = o - a,
                h = b(this.get(r, a), this.get(s, a), l),
                d = b(this.get(r, i), this.get(s, i), l);
            return b(h, d, c)
        }
        print() {
            let t = "";
            for (let e = 0; e < this.height; e++) {
                for (let n = 0; n < this.width; n++) t += this.get(n, e) < .5 ? "K" : "T";
                t += "\n"
            }
            return t
        }
        pack() {
            const t = [],
                e = Math.ceil(this.data.length / 32);
            for (let n = 0; n < e; n++) {
                let e = 0;
                for (let t = 0; t < 32; t++) this.data[t + 32 * n] > .5 && (e = L(e, t));
                t.push(e)
            }
            return t
        }
        unpack(t, e) {
            for (let n = 0; n < e; n++) {
                const e = t[Math.floor(n / 32)],
                    o = n % 32;
                this.data[n] = C(e, o) ? 1 : 0
            }
        }
    }

    function C(t, e) {
        return (t >> e) % 2 != 0
    }

    function L(t, e) {
        return t | 1 << e
    }
    const T = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789",
        j = new N(8, 11),
        O = {};
    ! function(t, e, n, o, r) {
        const a = e * n,
            s = Math.ceil(a / 32);
        for (let r = 0; r < o.length; r++) {
            const i = new N(e, n),
                l = r * s;
            i.unpack(t.slice(l, l + s), a);
            const c = o[r];
            O[c] = i
        }
    }([1667446300, 1667465059, 25443, 1667457855, 1667457855, 16227, 50553662, 50529027, 15971, 1667445535, 1667457891, 7987, 50529151, 50529087, 32515, 50529151, 50529087, 771, 50553662, 1667457915, 32355, 1667457891, 1667457919, 25443, 202116159, 202116108, 16140, 808464504, 858796080, 7731, 456352611, 857411343, 25443, 50529027, 50529027, 32515, 2138530659, 1667984235, 25443, 1734828899, 1936948079, 25443, 1667457854, 1667457891, 15971, 1667457855, 50544483, 771, 1667457854, 1868784483, 6305371, 1667457855, 858987327, 25443, 100885310, 1613764620, 15971, 404232447, 404232216, 6168, 1667457891, 1667457891, 15971, 1667457891, 912483171, 2076, 1801675619, 2137746283, 13878, 912483171, 1664490524, 25443, 858993459, 202120755, 3084, 811622527, 50727960, 32515, 1801675582, 1667984235, 15971, 404626456, 404232216, 32280, 1616929598, 101455920, 32515, 1616929598, 1616928828, 15971, 1010315296, 813642550, 12336, 50529151, 1616928831, 15971, 50529852, 1667457855, 15971, 1616929663, 202119216, 3084, 1667457854, 1667457854, 15971, -471604290, -522125597, 8429232], 8, 11, T);
    var H = 8,
        B = 11,
        z = function(t) {
            return O[t] || j
        };
    const q = ["abs", ...],
        F = " " + T;
    ! function(t) {
        for (let e = t.length - 1; e > 0; e--) {
            const n = Math.floor(Math.random() * e);
            [t[e], t[n]] = [t[n], t[e]]
        }
    }(q), q.unshift("cvb"), q.unshift("dfg"), q.unshift("ert");
    const D = new Array(3).fill(0),
        R = new Array(3).fill(0),
        V = new Array(3).fill(0);
    let W = 0;
    const P = new N(3 * H + 0, B);

    function _(t, e) {
        if (t.frame % 300 == 0) {
            const t = (function(t) {
                if ("string" != typeof t) return !1;
                if (3 != t.length) return !1;
                for (const e in t)
                    if (-1 == F.indexOf(e)) return !1;
                return !0
            }(e) ? e : q[W]).toUpperCase();
            R.fill(0);
            for (let e = 0; e < t.length; e++) R[e] = F.indexOf(t[e]);
            W = (W + 1) % q.length;
            for (let t = 0; t < 3; t++) V[t] = 6 * t
        }
        if (t.frame % 2 == 1) {
            for (let t = 0; t < 3; t++) 0 == V[t] ? D[t] != R[t] && (D[t] = (D[t] + 1) % F.length) : V[t]--;
            for (let t = 0; t < 3; t++) {
                const e = (H + 0) * t,
                    n = 0,
                    o = D[t];
                P.setBmp(z(F[o]), e, n)
            }
        }
    }
    const {
        min: I,
        max: U,
        sin: X,
        cos: $,
        floor: J,
        round: Y,
        random: K
    } = Math, Z = [];
    Z.push("  "), Z.push("+ "), Z.push(" ."), Z.push("+ "), Z.push(" ,"), Z.push("· "), Z.push(": "), Z.push("• ");
    const G = " .,·-•─~+:;=*π’“”!?#$@aàbcdefghijklmnoòpqrstuüvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ│0123456789%()".split(""),
        Q = " .·•-+=:;*ABC0123!*".split(""),
        tt = " ·-•~+:*abcXYZ*".split("");
    let et = J(K() * Z.length);
    Q[Q.length - 1] = Z[et][0], tt[tt.length - 1] = Z[et][1];
    for (const t of Z) - 1 == G.indexOf(t[0]) && G.push(t[0]), -1 == G.indexOf(t[1]) && G.push(t[1]);
    const nt = G.reduce(((t, e, n) => (t[e] = n, t)), {});

    function ot(t) {
        const e = null == t ? 0 : t.length;
        return e ? t[Math.floor(Math.random() * e)] : void 0
    }

    function rt(t, e, n) {
        return at(b(t.r, e.r, n), b(t.g, e.g, n), b(t.b, e.b, n))
    }

    function at(t, e, n, o = 1) {
        return {
            r: t,
            g: e,
            b: n,
            a: o
        }
    }

    function st(t) {
        let e = Math.round(t.r).toString(16).padStart(2, "0"),
            n = Math.round(t.g).toString(16).padStart(2, "0"),
            o = Math.round(t.b).toString(16).padStart(2, "0");
        return void 0 === t.a ? "#" + e + n + o : "#" + e + n + o + Math.round(255 * t.a).toString(16).padStart(2, "0")
    }

    function it(t) {
        return {
            a: 1,
            r: t >> 16 & 255,
            g: t >> 8 & 255,
            b: 255 & t
        }
    }
    const lt = [it(43690), it(11141120), it(11162880), it(5592575), it(5635925), it(5636095), it(16733525), it(16733695), it(16777215)],
        ct = {
            a: at(160, 160, 160),
            b: at(135, 135, 135)
        },
        ht = { ...ct
        },
        dt = function() {
            const t = 256,
                e = new Array(t),
                n = new Array(512);
            for (let o = 0; o < t; o++) e[o] = Math.random(), n[o] = o;
            for (let e = 0; e < t; e++) {
                const o = Math.floor(Math.random() * t);
                [n[e], n[o]] = [n[o], n[e]], n[e + t] = n[e]
            }
            let o, r, a, s, i, l, c, h, d, u, f, g, p, m, w, y;
            return function(x, v) {
                return o = Math.floor(x), r = Math.floor(v), a = x - o, s = v - r, i = (o + t) % t, l = (i + 1 + t) % t, c = (r + t) % t, h = (c + 1 + t) % t, d = e[n[n[i] + c]], u = e[n[n[l] + c]], f = e[n[n[i] + h]],
                    g = e[n[n[l] + h]], p = M(0, 1, a), m = M(0, 1, s), w = b(d, u, p), y = b(f, g, p), b(w, y, m)
            }
        }(),
        ut = {
            colorA: 0,
            colorB: 0,
            radiusSq: 0,
            movAmt: 0,
            scale: 0,
            data: []
        },
        ft = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("main div")).map((t => new m(t))),
        gt = new m(document.body);
    let pt, mt, wt = gt.property("--font-size-change");

    function bt(t, e) {
        for (const n of t.childNodes)
            if (0 == n.childNodes.length) {
                if (n.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                    const t = n.textContent.trim();
                    if (t) {
                        const o = n.parentNode.tagName,
                            r = {
                                text: t,
                                tag: o
                            };
                        if ("A" == o) {
                            const t = n.parentNode.attributes,
                                e = t.target ? ` target='${t.target.nodeValue}'` : "",
                                o = t.href ? ` href='${t.href.nodeValue}'` : "";
                            r.beginHTML = `<a${o}${e}>`, r.endHTML = "</a>"
                        }
                        e.push(r)
                    }
                } else if (n.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    const t = {
                        tag: n.tagName
                    };
                    e.push(t)
                }
            } else bt(n, e)
    }
    "ontouchstart" in window ? document.addEventListener("touchstart", (function(t) {
        t.target.href && (t.preventDefault(), location.href = t.target.href)
    })) : document.addEventListener("mousedown", (function(t) {
        0 === t.button && t.target.href && (t.preventDefault(), "_blank" == t.target.target ? window.open(t.target.href) : location.href = t.target.href)
    }));
    var yt = Object.freeze({
        __proto__: null,
        rgb: at,
        rgb2hex: st,
        boot: function(t, e, n) {
            pt = t.cols, mt = t.rows;
            const o = pt * mt;
            for (let t = 0; t < o; t++) {
                const e = Math.floor(t / pt),
                    n = t % pt;
                ut.data[t] = {
                    fade: 0,
                    heat: Math.floor(n / 4 + 2 * e) + 2,
                    curr: 0
                }
            }
        },
        pre: function(t, e, n, o) {
            const r = gt.property("--font-size-change");
            if (wt != r && (t.metrics._update(), wt = r), pt != t.cols || mt != t.rows) {
                pt = t.cols, mt = t.rows;
                const e = pt * mt;
                for (let t = 0; t < e; t++) ut.data[t] = {
                    fade: 0,
                    heat: 0,
                    curr: 0
                }
            }
            if ("white" == o.color) ut.colorA = "lightgray",
                ut.colorB = "white";
            else if (o.color) t.frame % 2e3 == 0 && (ct.a = ot(lt), ct.b = ot(lt)), ht.a = rt(ht.a, ct.a, .01), ht.b = rt(ht.b, ct.b, .01), ut.colorA = st(ht.a), ut.colorB = st(ht.b);
            else {
                const t = function(t, e) {
                    const n = t.x - e.x,
                        o = t.y - e.y;
                    return Math.sqrt(n * n + o * o)
                }(e, e.p);
                ut.radiusSq *= .8, ut.radiusSq = I(ut.radiusSq + .3 * t, 10);
                const n = t > .1 ? .008 : 0;
                if (ut.movAmt = I(ut.movAmt + n, 1), ut.movAmt < .3)
                    for (ht.a = ot(lt), ht.b = ot(lt); ht.b == ht.a;) ht.b = ot(lt);
                const o = function(t, e, n) {
                    const o = w((n - t) / (e - t), 0, 1);
                    return o * o * o * (o * (6 * o - 15) + 10)
                }(.3, .8, ut.movAmt);
                ut.colorA = st(rt(ct.a, ht.a, o)), ut.colorB = st(rt(ct.b, ht.b, o))
            }
            "screensaver" == o.mode && t.frame % 3e3 == 0 && (et = J(K() * Z.length)), 1 == ut.movAmt && (et = J(K() * Z.length));
            const a = Q[Q.length - 1];
            if (a != Z[et][0]) {
                const t = (nt[a] + 1) % G.length;
                Q[Q.length - 1] = G[t]
            }
            const s = tt[tt.length - 1];
            if (s != Z[et][1]) {
                const t = (nt[s] + 1) % G.length;
                tt[tt.length - 1] = G[t]
            }
            ut.movAmt = U(ut.movAmt - .003, 0);
            const i = t.cols < 80 ? 1.3 : .8;
            ut.scale += .01 * (i - ut.scale);
            const l = t.metrics.aspect,
                c = P.width / P.height / l;
            let h, d;
            if (c < t.cols / t.rows) {
                const e = t.rows;
                h = 1 / e / c / ut.scale, d = 1 / e / ut.scale
            } else {
                const e = t.cols;
                h = 1 / e / ut.scale, d = 1 / e * c / ut.scale
            }
            const u = 4e-4 * t.time;
            _(t, o && o.word ? o.word : "");
            const f = function(t, e, n, o, r) {
                return o + (t - e) / (n - e) * (r - o)
            }($(u), -1, 1, 1.2, .5);
            let g, p, m, b, y, x, M;
            for (let t = 0; t < mt; t++)
                for (let e = 0; e < pt; e++) g = h * (e - .5 * pt) + .5, p = d * (t - .5 * mt) + .5,
                    m = g + .5 * (dt(g * f + u, p * f) - .5), b = p + 1.8 * (dt(g * f, p * f + u) - .5), y = Math.floor(m * P.width), x = Math.floor(b * P.height), M = e + t * pt, ut.data[M].tex = U(P.sample(m, b), P.get(y, x))
        },
        main: function(t, e, n, o, r) {
            const a = t.index,
                s = U(ut.data[a].tex, ut.data[a].fade),
                i = (t.x - n.x) * e.metrics.aspect,
                l = t.y - n.y,
                c = i * i + l * l;
            if (c < ut.radiusSq) {
                const t = nt[0] + J(ut.radiusSq - c);
                ut.data[a].curr = t, ut.data[a].heat = 1
            }
            ut.data[a].fade = .95 * s;
            const h = (t.x + t.y) % 2 ? Q : tt;
            return {
                char: h[J(s * (h.length - 1))],
                color: s >= .99 ? ut.colorA : ut.colorB
            }
        },
        post: function(t, e, n, o) {
            if ("screensaver" == o.mode) return;
            const r = t.metrics,
                a = [];
            let s = 0;
            const i = gt.property("--display-mode");
            for (const e of ft) {
                const n = [];
                bt(e.DOMElement, n), e.updateBB();
                const o = e.x(r),
                    l = e.y(r),
                    c = e.width(r);
                e.height(r);
                let h = o,
                    d = l;
                for (let e of n)
                    if ("BR" == e.tag) d += 1,
                        h = o, s = U(s, d);
                    else if ("DIV" == e.tag) {
                    const n = E(e.text, c),
                        o = A(n.text, h, d, ut.data, t.cols, t.rows);
                    h = o.offset.col + 1, d = o.offset.row, s = U(s, n.numLines)
                } else if ("A" == e.tag && e.text) {
                    const n = E(e.text, c),
                        o = A({
                            text: n.text,
                            aheat: 1
                        }, h, d, ut.data, t.cols, t.rows);
                    for (const t of o.wrapInfo) t.first.beginHTML = e.beginHTML, t.last.endHTML = e.endHTML;
                    h = o.offset.col + 1, d = o.offset.row, s = U(s, n.numLines)
                }
                a.push({
                    x: o,
                    y: l,
                    displayMode: i,
                    width: c
                })
            }
            for (const e of a) "rows" == e.displayMode ? k({
                char: "─"
            }, e.x, e.y - 1, e.width, 1, ut.data, t.cols, t.rows) : "cols" == e.displayMode && k({
                char: "│"
            }, e.x - 1, 0, 1, s, ut.data, t.cols, t.rows);
            for (let e = 0; e < n.length; e++) {
                const o = ut.data[e];
                o.char && (o.heat = Math.max(o.heat, o.aheat || 0), 1 == o.heat ? o.curr != nt[o.char] ? (o.char = G[o.curr], (t.frame + e) % 2 == 0 && (o.curr = (o.curr + 1) % G.length)) : o.heat = 0 : o.heat > 1 && (o.heat--, o.char = G[o.curr]), n[e] = { ...o
                }, delete ut.data[e].char, delete ut.data[e].beginHTML, delete ut.data[e].endHTML, delete ut.data[e].color)
            }
        }
    });
    return t.boot = function(t) {
        const e = document.querySelector("PRE");
        f(yt, {
            element: e,
            fps: 30,
            allowSelect: !1
        }, t), document.addEventListener("keydown", (t => {
            "f" == t.key && (e.requestFullscreen ? document.fullscreenElement ? document.exitFullscreen() : e.requestFullscreen() : e.webkitRequestFullscreen && (document.webkitFullscreenElement ? document.webkitExitFullscreen() : e.webkitRequestFullscreen()))
        }))
    }, Object.defineProperty(t, "__esModule", {
        value: !0
    }), t
}({});
```

help me please with this ascii floating thing

Comment: I’m afraid I don’t understand the question. What is a JS element and what is the floating ASCII? Are you trying to stop it showing any of the random strings that are held in in const s? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.